# Garbage output on raspberry pi3 B/B+ when running and OCI container

Tags: docker, uart, tty, runc

I am running simple docker busybox container (converted to an OCI bundle) using docker-runC (https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec) on a raspberry pi3, connected to a host via a UART terminal. The connection is done through pins 6-8-10 on the GPIO, using a UART to USB converter (C232HD USB to UART). Terminal settings : 115200 bps ,8 data / 1 stop bits, none parity and flow control.
I get garbage only when container internal process (in this case the Bourne shell prompt, but anything else will output the same garbage) outputs to the screen.
The problem won't occur when running the same container on imx7s WaRP7 device does (same architecture), or when connecting the raspberry pi3 with an HDMI cable to a screen.

Attached is a print screen of the garbage I see. The config.json file is the default (docker-runc spec) without changes.
I am running with process/env/TERM=xterm and process/terminal=true.
Does anyone have an idea why do I get this garbage only on raspberry pi3 and while using UART (not on other devices, and not when using HDMI) and can give me some direction on how to deal with this problem?

[image]

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try switching

```
"terminal": true
```

to

```
"terminal": false
```

in config.json.